# html input type=file -- Select a file from iCloud

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova, icloud

I'm developing a Cordova / PhoneGap-based application that has an embedded text editor. To access selected files, I'm having the user browse the mobile device by using the html `<input type=file>` element:

```
<div class="control-row">
  <label for="selFile" class="topcoat-button">{{t 'view.lblSelect'}}</label>
  <input type="file" value="" id="selFile" multiple>
</div>
```

On iOS, however, clicking on the input element brings up Photos instead of allowing me to pick iCloud documents. Is there a way to select iCloud documents from Cordova / PhoneGap?

Comment: no, that's how input file works on the UIWebView, it's not a cordova problem, you might try to create a plugin to choose files from iCloud documents

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know if the WKWebView has this same behavior?

Comment: I think it should work the same way it works on the UIWebView, but never tried

Answer (score 2):

It's 2017 August Even I was facing the same problem after some research I found an exact solution for this. Go to Xcode ->Select your project -> Capabilities -> iCloud and enable it. Now it will work.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the same but it does not show the icloud option in the ipa. If we run directly it shows. Any idea?

Comment: Your saying, if you run the app on simulator or connected device it works, but if you generate ipa and share it with people it is not working, am I correct?

Comment: Exactly and same error in the "Relese" build too. Especially this error occurs on ios10.3.3 and it works good on ios 11.0. Any idea?

Comment: Visit your Apple Developer account and select your app id and in capabilities enable iCloud. Download the new provisioning profile and add it to your app. Rebuild the app and distribute. Let me know, if still issue is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The attr "multiple" is not compatibile with icloud file, you can try to remove it and it will be work fine,but you can only select one file of couse

```
<div class="control-row">
  <label for="selFile" class="topcoat-button">{{t 'view.lblSelect'}}</label>
  <input type="file" value="" id="selFile" >
</div>
```