# input type file not showing icloud option on file browser for ios in cordova application

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework

i am using the file input control to browse a file in my cordova application.On ios i also need to list out icloud option but it is not listing the icloud option on ios platform

```
<html>
<head>
<title>input file test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form">
<input name="myfile" type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadDoc()" class="image-selection" size="30" id="uploaddoc" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but it works in safari browser

Comment: Do you select an image right

Comment: i don't even get the icloud icon on file browser in ios platform

Comment: Even I have the same problem did you get any solution?

Comment: I have make it working, please find my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45794236/7824672

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I have tried the same but it does not show the icloud option in the ipa. If we run directly it shows. Any idea?